# Filtering EKEvent with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I have an NSArray with EKEvents, that I need to filter down to a clean list.

I'm looking for an **NSPredicate** that filters out all Events of which the 'title' attribute, which is **an NSString, starts with a numeric value**.

So, I want to take out those Titles that look like *'123Something'* and *'8somethingElse'* but keep *'Anything123'* and of course *'specificallyThisOne'*.

I rely on your smartness, and, since I really don't have a clue on where to get started, an explanation would also highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSPredicate` supports regular expression which provides the most convenient way to filter strings.

This is an example with a custom array of dictionaries, it's supposed to work also with an array of `EKEvent`.

The regex filters all strings which

- start `^`
- **not** with one or more digits `\\D+`
- and ignore the rest of the string `.*$`.

Since you didn't mention the language this is Swift:

```
let array = [["name" : "alpha", "title" : "123Something"],
             ["name" : "beta", "title" : "8somethingElse"],
             ["name" : "gamma", "title" : "Anything123"],
             ["name" : "delta", "title" : "specificallyThisOne"]]


let regex = "^\\D+.*$"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"title MATCHES %@", regex)

let filteredArray = (array as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
print(filteredArray)
```

It's even possible without `NSPredicate` using the native `filter` function

```
let filteredArray =  array.filter { $0["title"]!.rangeOfString(regex, options: .RegularExpressionSearch) != nil }
```

Comment: Thanks, that (almost) did the trick, but likely because I  didn't express myself correctly. The resulting filteredArray should contain 'Anything123' and filter out '123Something'. Is that a matter of adding an exclamation somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I fixed the regex, it's just capital D instead of d.

Comment: You're a hero! I promise I will start investigating RegEx.